# PDF toUnicode CMap glyph mapping

Tags: iphone, pdf, unicode, mapping

Is there anyway to get a character unicode that didn't provided in PDF toUnicode table?
or did I miss something when mapping the character?

I can't find code point <02DD> which will map to a T (uppercase)character <0054>. 
I think there will be a way to get the character, cause Preview (Mac APP) can search the text? I wonder where did I miss??????

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
57 beginbfchar
<0001> <0020>
<0002> <0021>
<0003> <0026>
<0004> <2019>
<0005> <002C>
<0006> <002D>
<0007> <002E>
<0008> <003A>
<0009> <003F>
<000A> <0040>
<000B> <0041>
<000C> <0042>
<000D> <0043>
<000E> <0044>
<000F> <0045>
<0010> <0046>
<0011> <0047>
<0012> <0048>
<0013> <0049>
<0014> <004A>
<0015> <004B>
<0016> <004C>
<0017> <004D>
<0018> <004F>
<0019> <0050>
<001A> <0052>
<001B> <0053>
<001C> <0054>
<001D> <0055>
<001E> <0057>
<001F> <0059>
<0020> <2018>
<0021> <0061>
<0022> <0062>
<0023> <0063>
<0024> <0064>
<0025> <0065>
<0026> <0066>
<0027> <0067>
<0028> <0068>
<0029> <0069>
<002A> <006A>
<002B> <006B>
<002C> <006C>
<002D> <006D>
<002E> <006E>
<002F> <006F>
<0030> <0070>
<0031> <0072>
<0032> <0073>
<0033> <0074>
<0034> <0075>
<0035> <0077>
<0036> <0079>
<0037> <007A>
<0038> <FB01>
<0039> <00FC>
endbfchar
endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous strategies for finding a value when no ToUnicode CMap is provided, none of them are ideal.

You can examine the Encoding of the font to see if its standard, if it is then you 'might' be in luck, assuming that the font isn't lying.

You can do the same with the Ordering and Registry of CIDFonts.

Failing that, you can try treating the character code as a Unicode code point. None of these are guaranteed to work.

You haven't said *why* you expect to find a mapping for the character code 0x02DD.

Note that ToUnicode CMaps don't map to characters, they map to Unicode (UTF-16 IIRC) code points.

Maybe you could put the entire PDF file somewhere ? Looking at bits makes it hard to figure out what's going on.